# CollectionView Cell add 1px boarder become 2px

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

The designer need my each collectionView Cell have a 1px boarder,Like below:

[image]

And my implementation show,seem some border overlap and become 2px，Is there other easy way to get it done? Thanks for help.

[image]

Here is the main code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

ServiceCategoryCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ServiceCategoryCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.entity = _categoryList[indexPath.row];

[cell.contentView addBorderWithWidth:0.5f hexColorString:@"#EFEFF4" cornerRadius:0];

return cell;
}

- (void)setupCollectionView{

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowFayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowFayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
flowFayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
flowFayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
flowFayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.keyWindowWidth/4, self.contentView.height);

_categoryCollectionVIew.delegate = self;
_categoryCollectionVIew.dataSource  = self;
_categoryCollectionVIew.scrollEnabled = NO;
_categoryCollectionVIew.collectionViewLayout = flowFayout;

[_categoryCollectionVIew registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ServiceCategoryCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ServiceCategoryCollectionViewCell"];
}

-(void)addBorderWithWidth:(float)width hexColorString:(NSString *)color cornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius{

    self.layer.borderWidth = width;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:color alpha:1].CGColor;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution Of Overlapping CollectionView Cell Border:**

add bottom and right side border through CALayer()

**Objective c:**

```
CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.height - 1, 
cell.contentView.frame.width, 1);
[cell.layer.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];


CALayer *rightBorder = [CALayer layer];
rightBorder.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.width, 0, 1, 
cell.contentView.frame.height);
[cell.layer.layer addSublayer:rightBorder];
```

**Swift :**

```
     let rightborder = CALayer()
    rightborder.frame = CGRect(x:cell.frame.width - 1,y: 0, width: 1, height: cell.frame.height)
    rightborder.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor;
    cell.layer.addSublayer(rightborder)


    let bottomborder = CALayer()
    bottomborder.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.frame.height - 1, width: cell.frame.width, height: 1)
    bottomborder.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor;
    cell.layer.addSublayer(bottomborder)
```

Comment: Solution to swift tech solved my problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know its work but first try open `simulator` in fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

This is simulator problem, check you code in device and then compare.

Comment: Run on device and all border width is 2px

Comment: In below line try 0.4f instead 0.5f

[cell.contentView addBorderWithWidth:0.5f hexColorString:@"#EFEFF4" cornerRadius:0];